# How to release a `Hidden` UIView from memory?

Tags: ios, swift, memory

I'm used to setting up views in StoryBoard and set inactivated views as `Hidden`, but I also don't want them to take up too much unnecessary memory. How to release a UIView when it is hidden or inactive?

By the way I'm programming in Swift. Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't. if you want to hide the view, then hide it. if you purge it from memory, you'll need to recreate it later. this seems pretty much like premature optimization.

Comment: So hiding a UIView is not that wasteful of memory? Even though it's not a good practice?

Comment: worrying about what's wasteful before actually measuring it (and before it causes actual problems) is what's bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *inactivate* the views *forever*, you need to remove them from their superviews (`view.removeFromSuperview()` will do the job for you here). Otherwise it wouldn't make much sense to release it from memory since you'll have to reinstantiate the same view later on again which in my opinion is unnecessary overhead compared to just hiding and unhiding it.

Answer (score 1):

I am agreed with [The Paramagnetic Croissant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3477950/the-paramagnetic-croissant). But if you want to remove it then you can use:

```
YourView.removeFromSuperview()
```